# Python, calling scipy.integrate.solve_ivp with conditions for a second degree spring-mass system

Tags: python, scipy, ode, solver, differential-equations

I am trying to solve a 2 Degrees of Freedom spring mass system like this using `solve_ivp` function in `scipy.integrate`.

The link of the image is given below. This is my first post. so stack overflow is not letting me post images.

[link of the image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aLg7hpsnfXRpHVTsUaxUP1txxIgDKfq8/view?usp=sharing)

Here, when the mass `m1` goes beyond `d` in the negative region, `K1` becomes double i.e, when

```
-infinity < x1 <= -1, k1 = 14
-1 < x1 <= infinity, k1 = 7
```

This is the code that I have written without the second spring for `m1`

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def F(t, y):
##########################################################################################################################################################################################
    m1 = 3
    m2 = 5

    k1 = 7
    k2 = 9

    c1 = 1
    c2 = 2

    f1 = 40*np.cos(3*t)
    f2 = 0
##########################################################################################################################################################################################

    M = np.array([
        [m1, 0],
        [0, m2]
    ])

    C = np.array([
        [c1 + c2, -c2],
        [-c2, c2]
    ])

    K = np.array([
        [k1 + k2, -k2],
        [-k2, k2]
    ])

    A = np.vstack([
        np.hstack([
            np.zeros((2, 2)), 
            np.eye(2, 2)
        ]), 
        np.hstack([
            -np.matmul(np.linalg.inv(M), K), 
            -np.matmul(np.linalg.inv(M), C)
        ])
    ])

    B = np.vstack([
        np.zeros((2, 2)), 
        np.linalg.inv(M)
    ])

    F = np.array([
        [f1],
        [f2]
    ])

    yvec = np.array([[y[i] for i in range(4)]]).T

    ydot = np.matmul(A, yvec) + np.matmul(B, F)

    return ydot

####################################################################################################################################################################################
start_time = 0
end_time = 60
delta_t = 0.01

initial_position_m_1 = 2
initial_velocity_m_1 = 1

initial_position_m_2 = 5
initial_velocity_m_2 = 3
####################################################################################################################################################################################

TE = np.arange(start_time, end_time, delta_t)

time_interval = np.array([start_time, end_time])
initial_conditions = np.array([initial_position_m_1, initial_position_m_2, initial_velocity_m_1, initial_velocity_m_2])

sol = solve_ivp(F, time_interval, initial_conditions, t_eval = TE, vectorized=True, method = 'RK45')


T = sol.t
Y = sol.y
dis_m_1 = sol.y[0]
dis_m_2 = sol.y[1]
vel_m_1 = sol.y[2]
vel_m_2 = sol.y[3]

plt.plot(T, dis_m_1)
plt.plot(T, np.full((len(dis_m_1)), -1, dtype='int32'))
plt.title("Displacement of m1 vs time")
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.show()

plt.plot(T, dis_m_2)
plt.title("Displacement of m2 vs time")
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.show()

plt.plot(T, vel_m_1)
plt.title("Velocity of m1 vs time")
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.show()

plt.plot(T, vel_m_2)
plt.title("Velocity of m2 vs time")
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.show()
```

This is the plot of displacement of `m1` without the second spring.

[link of the image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Xr7paZp1h9EnjKQnM3nH56ZId0HR_gw_/view?usp=sharing)

Whenever the mass `m1` goes below the horizontal line, `k1` should be equal to `14`. How can I apply an if else condition in the `return` statement of the following code for 2 springs for `m1`

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def F(t, y):
##########################################################################################################################################################################################
    m1 = 3
    m2 = 5

    k1 = 7
    k2 = 9

    c1 = 1
    c2 = 2

    f1 = 40*np.cos(3*t)
    f2 = 0
##########################################################################################################################################################################################

    M = np.array([
        [m1, 0],
        [0, m2]
    ])

    C = np.array([
        [c1 + c2, -c2],
        [-c2, c2]
    ])

    K = np.array([
        [k1 + k2, -k2],
        [-k2, k2]
    ])

    KK = np.array([
        [2*k1 + k2, -k2],
        [-k2, k2]
    ])

    A = np.vstack([
        np.hstack([
            np.zeros((2, 2)), 
            np.eye(2, 2)
        ]), 
        np.hstack([
            -np.matmul(np.linalg.inv(M), K), 
            -np.matmul(np.linalg.inv(M), C)
        ])
    ])

    AA = np.vstack([
        np.hstack([
            np.zeros((2, 2)), 
            np.eye(2, 2)
        ]), 
        np.hstack([
            -np.matmul(np.linalg.inv(M), KK), 
            -np.matmul(np.linalg.inv(M), C)
        ])
    ])


    B = np.vstack([
        np.zeros((2, 2)), 
        np.linalg.inv(M)
    ])

    F = np.array([
        [f1],
        [f2]
    ])

    yvec = np.array([[y[i] for i in range(4)]]).T

    ydot1 = np.matmul(A, yvec) + np.matmul(B, F)    # k1 = 7 
    ydot2 = np.matmul(AA, yvec) + np.matmul(B, F)   # k1 = 14

    return ???????

####################################################################################################################################################################################
start_time = 0
end_time = 60
delta_t = 0.01

initial_position_m_1 = 2
initial_velocity_m_1 = 1

initial_position_m_2 = 5
initial_velocity_m_2 = 3
####################################################################################################################################################################################

TE = np.arange(start_time, end_time, delta_t)

time_interval = np.array([start_time, end_time])
initial_conditions = np.array([initial_position_m_1, initial_position_m_2, initial_velocity_m_1, initial_velocity_m_2])

sol = solve_ivp(F, time_interval, initial_conditions, t_eval = TE, vectorized=True, method = 'RK45')


T = sol.t
Y = sol.y
dis_m_1 = sol.y[0]
dis_m_2 = sol.y[1]
vel_m_1 = sol.y[2]
vel_m_2 = sol.y[3]

plt.plot(T, dis_m_1)
plt.plot(T, np.full((len(dis_m_1)), -1, dtype='int32'))
plt.title("Displacement of m1 vs time")
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.show()

plt.plot(T, dis_m_2)
plt.title("Displacement of m2 vs time")
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.show()

plt.plot(T, vel_m_1)
plt.title("Velocity of m1 vs time")
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.show()

plt.plot(T, vel_m_2)
plt.title("Velocity of m2 vs time")
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.show()
```

I think it should look something like this.

```
if displacement_of_m1 <= -1:
    return ydot1
else:
    return ydot2
```

Can someone help? Thanks.

Comment: Alternatively to introducing the branch inside the derivatives function, you could use an event function for the threshold and restart the integration with the appropriate variant of the derivatives function.

Comment: Could you give some details on event functions in the solve_ivp function? I read the documentation but it is very short.

Comment: You could just set `k1 = 7 if y[0]>-1 else 14` or `k1=7; if y[0]<=-1: k1*=2` to avoid duplicating the whole construction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like

```
if y[0] < -1:
    return ydot2
return ydot1
```

here `y[0]`, `y[1]` ... upto `y[n]` are present and it could change depending on vectorized=True. Sometimes it will be `[x1, x2, x3, ..., v1, v2, v3...]` or `[x1, v1, x2, v2, x3, v3, ...]`